# Opening app with custom url scheme in ios app

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I have two url scheme, say, openView1:// and openView2:// . Now, when i click to openView1://, i want to pen view1. When i click to openView2://, i want to pen view2.

I did like following at appDelegate.m

```
 #import "Welcome_ResetPassword.h"
 @implementation AppDelegate

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:     (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation { 
 isopenView1= FALSE; //    isopenView1 is global varaible define in appDelegate.h 
 isopenView2= FALSE; // isopenView1 is global varaible define in appDelegate.h 
 if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"openView1"]) {
    isopenView1= TRUE;
    return isopenView1; 
}
else{
    isopenView2= TRUE;
    return isopenView2; 
}
```

}

now,

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
 if ( isopenView1) {
    //show view1 as app start 
 }else{
   //show view2 as app start 
 }
}
```

This is not working. How can I achieve it?

Comment: `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` might already be called if the app is running in the background. Just present the view in the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`

Answer (score 1):

I believe since iOS 5.0, url schemes are returned case insensitive (lowercase).